# Systematically replace ALL words in plain txt, with a new library of words in Excel

Tags: excel

I have created a list of morse code abbreviations in excel and now I want to transform any kind of text to these new words (abbreviations), by loading pages upon pages of text into the script to transform into a morse transscript.

For instance:

Once upon a time I was going to a beach and saw a cow

ONC UPN A TI I WS GG TO A BCH SS SAW A CW

I want this so that I can add words not in the list, and remove words that are never being used (manually though). This is because this list is from before the war and contains many unused words today, and so I want to optimize it for proper usage. It's the Evans Code if anyone is interested.

If the script could add 1 to the cell next to the words in excel for a count of how many times it's been replaced, that would also be great.

I have no idea of how to go about it, I just want to know if it is possible, and if so, please guide me on my way - I'm not asking you to do all the work, which I'm sure is not as straight-forward as it is on paper.

I've got a little knowledge of node.js and c++, but I don't know if either of those are the right languages for the task at hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea of how to go about it, I just want to know if it is possible, and if so, please guide me on my way.

Break the problem down into smaller tasks.

1. Choose a single programming language.  (Any of the languages you listed would be suitable.)
2. Get Excel to export the spreadsheet containing the dictionary as a CSV file.  (CSV files are easier for a program to read.)
3. Find a CVS reader library.  (Google it.)
4. Write a method to read the CSV into an in-memory data structure; e.g. a "map" or "dictionary" that maps from words to "evans code"
5. Write code to

   - read your input file a line at a time.
   - split each line into words
   - for each word, look the word in the dictionary (ignoring case) and replace with the code word
   - reassemble words into lines and write to output

Punctuation might make this a bit more complicated, but your example doesn't show any punctuation.

---

> I'm not asking you to do all the work, which I'm sure is not as straight-forward as it is on paper.

Actually, it *should be* pretty much as straight-forward as it is on paper.  Provided you get into it.

(But the longer you put off starting because it "looks hard", the harder it will actually be!  That kind of thought pattern tends to be self-fulfilling.)